# Is there any RealBasic studio for C language?

Tags: c, linux, user-interface, gnu, realbasic

Is there any RealBasic studio like for GNU C language, Where i just wrote in 1 minute GUI button and msgBox, took 2 minutes to make it and deploy application, very fast and rapid for cross platform. Full screen mode/timer etc all prepared by click of mouse, i am really impressed with the free demo version.

Please see screen shot, what i mean:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/UPzBP.png

```
  msgBox("Hello, Easy peasy gui and programming?")
```

Comment: Why are you trying to use C for this? All you will do is make your life miserable; you will not be able to make any use of any of the advantages of C, and you will suffer all the disadvantages of C.

Comment: And i also need fast rapdi GUI builders which is offered by RealBasic

Comment: there must be a mixed language option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you like the rapid development and cross-platform abilities of Real Studio and the RealBasic language, but need to use some external C libraries, there is a language feature called declares that can expose the C functions you need.

http://docs.realsoftware.com/index.php/Declare

Answer (score 0):

You can try GTK and its editor (cant remember its name)

Comment: If you happen to be running Linux.

Comment: Why did I voted down? Some one doesn't like GTK?

Comment: @Charlie GTK runs on windows as well. Well at least GIMP + GTK is running on windows Im 100% sure of that.

Comment: [Glade](http://glade.gnome.org/) is what you are thinking of, and does appear to have Windows binaries

Comment: I guess address tells all: http://php-gtk.eu/en/glade-3-341-build-for-windows-installer-included

Answer (score 0):

Well, no.  See, unlike RealBasic, C doesn't know about buttons, messages, boxes etc.  What you need is to look into some particular GUI library that supports C.

From what you're asking, I think you'd be much happier with another language than C; if you want a C-like language, Java and an IDE like NetBeans might suit you.

Comment: Can i have C libraries patched to RealBasic atleast? Which can allow me to trigger C functions by pressing realBasic buttons.

Comment: That means C is a long term programming which will take 1 year to build what can be done in 1 month with RealBasic. I mean lot of owners/investors dont want that much long term developments, they are kind of lazy, they want GUI + Application rapid gets done. In that case C is suicide choice of development compared to RealBasic.

Comment: @89899.3K: May be you should consider C++ for rapid development. IMHO C is more suited for system programming. For C++ there lots of GUI Tools, including QT.

Comment: @Cem Kalyoncu: IC thanks, You mean Qml of Qt as rapid development?

Comment: Is there any TCL/TK, Fltk sort of gui builders? Which can do RAD?

Comment: @89899.3K, yes. It's called: tcl. :)

Answer (score 0):

Real Studio has a C-based plugin SDK that allows you to create plugins that extend the framework.  Look into that if you want to take the benefits of Real Studio and combine it with the power of C.

Answer (score 0):

What about using Delphi's C++ Builder XE3? It's what you're looking for.
http://www.embarcadero.com/products/cbuilder
It can compile to windows and mac and very shortly they'll realease an update for IOS and Android
I used their Pascal RAD app builder before switching to realbasic. Honestly, if they had the ability to compile to OS X and Windows back in 2007, I never would have switched to realbasic.
Good LUck